R - st_intersection gives no intersections between line layer and random point layer that was CREATED from the line layer
I am trying to figure out why a random point layer that I have created based upon a line layer has NO intersections with that line layer... Below is reproducible code that shows the problem.
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

#### create dummy data frame of points
data <- data.frame(
  utme = c(294118.5, 294930.8, 333526.0, 334487.1, 317332.2,    288261.3),
  utmn   = c(4951635, 4952285, 4975957, 4976818, 4967509, 4945264),
  id = c (1,1,2,2,3,3))

#### Turn the points into lines by grouping by id 
lines <- data %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("utme", "utmn"), na.fail = FALSE, crs = "epsg:26920") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")


### randomly sample points along the lines
random_points <- st_sample(lines, size = 800)

## collapse list into dataframe and turn into sf point object
random_points <- do.call(rbind, random_points) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::rename(utmn = X1, utme = X2) %>%
  st_as_sf(., coords = c("utmn", "utme"), crs = "epsg:26920")


##### Intersect lines and points

intersection <- st_intersection(random_points, lines)

The result is that the intersection object has no rows. Since the random_points layer was sampled from the lines layer (and they are both in the same CRS - UTM Zone 20), I don't understand why there is no intersection. Incidentally when I conduct the same operation in QGIS, the problem also occurs.
Is there any obvious solution to this or an easy fix?
Thanks

Even a tiny buffer around the lines will give the expected result, e.g. st_intersection(random_points, st_buffer(lines, 1e-10)). I don't know whether this is an issue of floating point equality or not, but it does not appear to be safe to rely on intersection between zero-size points and zero-width lines.

Definitely a floating point equality issue, which does not get resolved for every case even when using functions such as sf::st_snap(). If your use case is to find the nearest line to each point, the method shown by Allan Cameron is probably the easiest fix. If you need your points to be incident to the lines, please update your question and explain what your goal is. This will help narrow down potential solutions.

Depending on your actual aim, you might find sfnetworks::st_network_blend() useful - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=st_network_blend , sf::st_intersection not implement all points

Thank you guys - st_buffer (with a tiny buffer) around the lines object works well. I am indeed just trying to find the nearest line to each point (pull in the data from the line layer into the point layer based upon the nearest line).
